# How to create a migration in YII?

Tags: php, yii

I have just started with YII and I am trying to create a new migration. I am using Xampp and it is located in the d drive of my system.

The command that I am trying to use is:

```
D:\xampp\php> d:\xampp\htdocs\yii\framework\yiic  migrate create create_project_table
```

When I run the above command nothing happens, neither do I get an error message nor there is any error.

I did manage to successfully create a shell by using

```
D:\xampp\php> d:\xampp\htdocs\yii\framework\yiic shell d:\xampp\htdocs\trackstar\index.php
```

I tried to search for any solution for the migration issue but they all seem to be linux based. Please let me know what I am missing here. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your can read this link http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.migration

Comment: @NanheKumar Thanks, I was a able to figure out a way after looking into the documentation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I managed to create the migration sucessfully. Turns out that I needed to use the yiic located in the protected folder of my application instead of the yiic located in framework folder of yii. The command that I used is

```
D:\xampp\php>D:\xampp\htdocs\trackstar\protected\yiic migrate create create_project_table
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found that you need a forward slash in my version.

```
yii migrate/create <migration_name>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to go to **protect** folder on your Yii project
Then run the comamnd:

```
php yiic migrate create create_new_table_name_table
```